# ElasticSearch PHP API Search by Field

Tags: php, elasticsearch

**Resolved**

I am trying to get a results back using the official elasticsearch 5.0 php package.  I can get the desired results via URL and cURL.

```
http://localhost:9200/index/doctype/_search?q=status:available
```

I get 8 hits and 8 hit results, as expected.

```js
curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/index/doctype/_search?pretty' -d'
{
    "query" : {
        "term" : { "status" : "available" }
    }
}'
```

I get 8 hits and 8 hit results, as expected.

Using the following various bits of code, I get 8 results but 0 hits.

```
$params['body']['query']['term']['status'] = 'available';
$params['q'] = 'status:available';
$params['body'] = [
        'query' => [
            'bool' => [
                'must' => [
                    ['match' => ['status' => 'available']],
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ];
```

Called via:

```php
$params = [
            'index' => 'index',
            'type' => 'doctype',
        ];

        $skip = !empty($_GET['page']) ? (int)$_GET['page'] - 1 : 0;
        $listings_per_page = 25;
        $params['from'] = $skip * $per_page;
        $params['size'] = $per_page;

        // show only available

        $params['body'] = [
            'query' => [
                'bool' => [
                    'must' => [
                        ['match' => ['status' => 'available']],
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        ];

        $hosts = [env('ES_HOST', 'elasticsearch') . ':' . env('ES_PORT', '9200')];
        $client = ClientBuilder::create()->setHosts($hosts)->build();
        $es_results = $client->search($params);
```

I have the index and doctype set properly in the $params as well in other bits of code. What could I be doing wrong here?

Comment: What do you mean with "I get 8 results but 0 hits."?

Comment: ElasticSearch will return the number of documents as well as the hits to the query.  The number of records is stored in $results['hits']['total'] and the records themselves are stored in $results['hits']['hits']; of which I get 8 total but empty hits.

Comment: ok I see, what if you add `$params['size'] = 10` to your code?

Comment: I actually already have that for pagination; I have specified from and size.

Comment: Can you show your full client code, it'll be easier to help you.

Comment: Updated to reflect more code.

Comment: In my opinion `from` has a value higher than 8 and that's the reason why you don't see any hits. Can you print out the value of `from` and `size`?

Comment: The problem was that my from and size parameters matched.  Logic error.

Comment: There you go, glad you figured it out!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is very likely that your `from` and `size` parameters are not computed correctly and `from` might be higher than 8, hence why you see `results.hits.total: 8` but nothing in `results.hits.hits`

Make sure that `from` is 0 and `size` is at least 8 (default is 10) and you'll see your hits.